# Wordpress menu not loading in the admin side appearence-> menu tab

Tags: menus, admin-menu

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: columns is not defined  load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:83

at Object.initToggles (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:83)
at Object.init (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:83)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:83)
at i (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2)
at Function.ready (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2)
initToggles @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:83

    init @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:83
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:83
i @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2
fireWith @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2
ready @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2
K @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-u&load[]=i-droppable,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,postbox,nav-menu&ver=4.9.9:2
```

please help me on this, it is happening in production

Comment: Looks like the variable `columns` in `/wp-admin/js/nav-menu.js` is not initialised, although it should be a global variable.

Comment: So what I need to do? I hven't done anything in the code.

Comment: I googled the error and found this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/menu-nav-page-error/ . Perhaps you could upgrade to a newer version of `Woocommerce`?

Comment: I do not have a woocommerce plugin

Comment: This is actually fixed. it was causing another plugin, so I just disabled that plugin and it is working now.